# Proc format in sas to hive

Tags: unix, hive, apache-pig

I have a program that is written in SAS and uses PROC FORMAT and is actually building some type of new data types for the columns to be assigned to... I need that to be rewritten in Hive/Pig or even Unix, need some ideas as to how to write that. Any suggestions would be welcome.

here is an example,

PROC FORMAT;

VALUE $ABCD
   '3000',
   '3001',
   '8816' - '8817',
   '8817' - '8815' = 'Y'
      OTHER  = 'N';

PUT(DDDD,$ABCD.) = 'Y'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proc Format is just an efficient way to write if/then logic, yes?
In SQL, you would use a `CASE` statement:

```
case 
  when <column> between 3000 and 3001 then 'Y'
  when <column> between 8816 and 8817 then 'Y'
  when <column> between 8815 and 8817 then 'Y'
else 'N'
end
```

Comment: That is a possibility I thought about, but then there is also that PUT statement in SAS that is there. What about that then? From the CASE statement perspective?